# Flask - ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, flask, import

I get the following error when trying to import from src package:

client.py

```
from . import create_app
from . models import db
from . models import Monitoring


app = create_app()
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from . models import db
    
app = Flask(__name__)

def create_app():
    db.init_app(app)
    return app


from src import routes
```

Project tree

```
.
├── manage.py
├── sf.py
├── src
│   ├── client.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── routes.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test.py
```

Error message:

```sh
(sensor_flora) edx@edx-HP-250-G3-Notebook-PC:~/VisualStudio/SensorFlora$ python src/client.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/client.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import create_app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: Also, there should not be any space between `.` and `models` in `from . models import db` and `from . models import Monitoring`

Comment: I run code with python src/client.py (through pyenv virtual environment)
I've edited my code with .models but doesn't make difference, I've got still error.
If I move clients.py at top level and then from src import create_app it works. But when I try to import it inside src I've got the error.

Comment: My comment on `.models` instead of `. models` was not the cause of your issue, but to avoid others, as it's wrong syntax

Comment: By doing `python src/client.py`, are you trying to test `client.py` only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: Fix `.models` and run `client.py` from inside `src` folder not outside it as `~$ python client.py`  this should fix your issue if you are only testing `client.py` file

Comment: For me your code works (when I comment out those imports which cannot work as you did not provide all code). But do not get the error you got. Maybe that is because I did a `FLASK_APP=src` before running `flask run`. I am not a big fan of relative imports as they make everything more complicated, see my link above. Also, when you are planning to restructure your project, I recommend the following links to read https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/
https://web.archive.org/web/20170615032800/https://enotuniq.org/
https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/08/test-as-installed.html

Comment: Please note, the mentioned "src" directory in the mentioned blog articles do not correspond to your "src" directory - you miss a package inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, I've appreciated it.

SOLUTION:

The problem was that the client.py script it's not executed by flask which has it's own path.
In fact, what I did is simply add a proper python path, at the top level (project) like so:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/home/usr/VisualStudio/MyProject"
```

Then I've changed all imports to absolute imports.

Finally I ran with python src/clients.py and it works.

TODO:
As client.py is a "standalone" script, nothing to do with the flask app, apart it uses the app like a package to import database and it's configurations, I though it was better to move the client.py in a separate package (because I need to run the script along the flask app).